# find $\cos\theta$ if $\sin\theta=\frac{3}{4}$ and $\tan\theta=\frac{9}{2}$

Tags: trigonometry

> If $\sin\theta=\frac{3}{4}$ and $\tan\theta=\frac{9}{2}$ then find $\cos\theta$

The solution is given in my reference as $\frac{1}{6}$.

$$
\cos\theta=\sqrt{1-\sin^2\theta}=\sqrt{1-\frac{9}{16}}=\sqrt{\frac{7}{16}}=\frac{\sqrt{7}}{4}
$$
$$
\cos\theta=\frac{1}{\sec\theta}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+\tan^2\theta}}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+\frac{81}{4}}}=\frac{2}{\sqrt{85}}
$$
$$
\cos\theta=\frac{\sin\theta}{\tan\theta}=\frac{\frac{3}{4}}{\frac{9}{2}}=\frac{3}{4}.\frac{2}{9}=\frac{1}{6}
$$
Why is it getting confused here ?

Comment: Check https://www.desmos.com/calculator/u8oikqddj5

Comment: It is confusing because no $\theta$ could satisfies both of the assumptions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because you have two different problems. Obviously (from your calculations which are correct) it can't be $\sin\theta=\frac{3}{4}$ and $\tan\theta=\frac{9}{2}$ at the same time.

Comment: You mean "can't", not "can" right?

Comment: Surely you mean "it **cannot** be"!

Comment: well. so u saying the actual question in my reference is wrong, right ?

Comment: Yes, that is what I'm saying.

Answer (score 1):

This is an impossible situation.  If you use the identity
$$\tan(\theta) = {\sin(\theta)\over\cos(\theta)},$$
you get $\cos(\theta) = 1/6$.

However, $\cos(\theta) = \sqrt{7}/4$ by the Pythagorean identity.

Comment: https://www.desmos.com/calculator/u8oikqddj5

Comment: Add a screenshot from this to your answer to give a visual answer for the OP

Comment: I think he can draw that.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is actually incorrect. Here is why:

Consider a right triangle and angle $\theta$ in that triangle such that $\sin\theta=\dfrac{3}{4}.$

That means that the right triangle has one leg $3$ and hypotenuse $4$. This implies that the other leg is $\sqrt{4^2-3^2}=\sqrt{7}.$

This implies that $\cos \theta=\dfrac{\sqrt{7}}4.$ Now also note that $\tan \theta \neq \frac 92$ as stated in your problem.